# Errors After Updating from Tex Live to Tex Live on Windows 10

Tags: texlive

- I use **TeX Live** (TL) on **Windows 10** in combination with **Texmaker**.
- Yesterday I wanted to update from TL 2019 to TL 2021.
- I switched from MiKTeX to TeX Live in 2019 so this is my first update.
- In order to update, I removed TL 2019 using the normal Windows mechanism (remove program).
- Then I installed TL 2021 and made sure that the Windows `PATH` variable includes the new TL location, see screenshot.

[image]
[image]

- Using the command line, `pdflatex` is available, see screenshot.
  [image]
- Running the MWE in Texmaker leads to an error message, see screenshot.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
adsdsd
\end{document}
```

---

> ```
> Process started
>
> fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order): fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf
> file for writing changes: fmtutil:
> c:/users/biest/.texlive2021/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf fmtutil
> [INFO]: writing formats under
> c:/users/biest/.texlive2021/texmf-var/web2c fmtutil [INFO]: Did not
> find entry for byfmt=pdflatex skipped fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 0
> fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
>
> Running the command C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe
>
> kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt The command name is C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\mktexfmt
>
> Process exited with error(s)
> ```

[image]

- Randomly searching the internet led me to `fmtutil --user --all` which results in the following output (`[WARNING]: You seem to have no formats defined in your fmtutil.cnf files!`), see screenshot.

[image: fmtutil --user --all]

**Question:** Do you know that's the problem and have maybe an idea to solve it?

Comment: It's a bit late, but you don't normally need to remove an old TeXLive.  TeXLive is designed so that you can just update your path to point to the newly installed one, and everything magically works.  I don't know if that's related to your current problem or not.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks for the comment. I maybe should have tried that first :).

Comment: also don't edit the question to say solved and have a solution, it messes up the question/answer format of the site.  Please leave the question as a question and post  (and accept) a self answer if you have a solution

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done!

Comment: You seem to have solved this, but running `tlmgr update --self -all` should both update your installation and re-run all the `fmtutil` commands.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks! I believe that I tried `tlmgr update --self -all` without success but I am not 100 % sure. But your comment may be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I just saw the the `texmf-local` folder is from 2019.
- I now delete all folders and try to install TL again...

[image]

- Looks good so far.

[image]

```
Installing [4147/4148, time/total: 33:22/33:22]: zxjatype [144k]
Installing [4148/4148, time/total: 33:22/33:22]: zztex [147k]
Time used for installing the packages: 33:23
running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist ...
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.
writing fmtutil.cnf to C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
writing updmap.cfg to C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
writing language.dat to C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
writing language.def to C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
writing language.dat.lua to C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var C:/texlive/2021/texmf-config C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist ...
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2021/texmf-config/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2021/texmf-config/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.
running updmap-sys --nohash ...done
re-running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var C:/texlive/2021/texmf-config ...
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Updating C:/texlive/2021/texmf-config/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Updated C:/texlive/2021/texmf-config/ls-R.
mktexlsr: Done.
setting up ConTeXt cache: running mtxrun --generate ...done
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all ...done
running path adjustment actions
finished with path adjustment actions
running package-specific postactions
3 Datei(en) kopiert
1 Datei(en) kopiert
Running fc-cache -v -r
finished with package-specific postactions

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 The following environment variables contain the string "tex"
 (case-independent).  If you're doing anything but adding personal
 directories to the system paths, they may well cause trouble somewhere
 while running TeX.  If you encounter problems, try unsetting them.
 Please ignore spurious matches unrelated to TeX.

    II=C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------


Willkommen bei TeX Live!


Schauen Sie in die C:/texlive/2021/index.html für Links auf die Dokumentation.
Die TeX Live Website (https://tug.org/texlive/) enthält Updates and Korrekturen. TeX Live ist ein vereintes Projekt der TeX Nutzergruppen weltweit, werden Sie Mitglied um ihre Arbeit zu unterstützen. Die Liste der Gruppen finden Sie unter https://tug.org/usergroups.html.
Logfile: C:/texlive/2021/install-tl.log
Installed on platform win32 at C:/texlive/2021
```

- Now it seems to work!

[image]